# How do I checkout files under Perforce from within Emacs?

Tags: version-control, emacs, file, perforce

I use Perforce for source control at work and I want to 'open for edit' files that under source control from within Emacs.

How can that be done? What do I need to setup in Emacs? Is there a plug in? I also want to perform other p4 operations such as submitting my changes, etc.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Perforce/Emacs Integration
http://p4el.sourceforge.net/p4.el.html

> Once you have p4.el installed and ready to go you can use emacs' built-in help to review p4.el's functions: C-x p ? will bring up the list. C-h f p4-xyz provides defun information for p4-xyz. Each Perforce command has a corresponding p4.el command. The `vc` model is not followed. Use 'C-x p help commands' for Perforce help...