# Perforce and Emacs

Tags: version-control, emacs, perforce

I'm looking to setup emacs to allow me to use perforce without having to use p4v.

I've had a look at the [emacs wiki](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/PerforceSCM) and a search on the [site](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/117394/how-do-i-checkout-files-under-perforce-from-within-emacs) but there only seems to be two options out there - both of which are pretty old. First option is [p4.el](http://p4el.sourceforge.net/) which was last updated in 2004. The second option is [the integration](http://public.perforce.com:8080/@md=d&cd=//guest/jonathan_kamens/&ra=s&c=uLL@//guest/jonathan_kamens/vc-p4/?ac=83) with emacs VC component, last updated in August 2007.

The second link above from [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/117394/how-do-i-checkout-files-under-perforce-from-within-emacs) seems to suggest using p4.el. Is that still the recommended advice? Does anyone have any tips or tricks they can share?

Any help \ advice much appreciated.

Chris

Comment: Funny you should mention that - another issue I have at the moment is that I can't seem to get git-p4 to work! It's really annoying, as I'd probably bypass most perforce interaction if I got it up and running.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, p4.el is still a recommended way to integrate perforce into emacs. It was well implemented which explains why it hasn't been updated since 2004.

I customized a couple of things, mostly to add and disable some shortcuts.

I added a possibility to call some p4v commands from emacs as well

```
(defun invoke-p4v-cmd (cmd)
  (let ((file (if (equal major-mode 'dired-mode)
                  (dired-get-file-for-visit)
                (buffer-file-name))))
    (when file
      (shell-command (concat "\"c:/Program Files/Perforce/p4v.exe\" -cmd \"" cmd " " file "\" &")))))

(defun op:p4v-timelapse ()
  "show revision tree"
  (interactive)
  (invoke-p4v-cmd "annotate"))

(define-key p4-prefix-map "T" 'op:p4v-timelapse)


(defun op:p4v-tree ()
  "show revision tree"
  (interactive)
  (invoke-p4v-cmd "tree"))

(define-key p4-prefix-map "g" 'op:p4v-tree)

(defun op:p4v-history ()
  "Show history"
  (interactive)
  (invoke-p4v-cmd "history"))

(define-key p4-prefix-map "x" 'op:p4v-history)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Just out of interest, I'm assuming there's no support for stashing in p4.el (stashing came way after)?

Comment: I'm still new to Perforce, but it seems that p4 shelve is similar to git stash. You can easily implement a p4-shelve emacs function based on p4.el

Comment: There’s been some work in CVS since version 10.6; see <http://p4el.cvs.sourceforge.net/viewvc/p4el/p4/> for an unreleased version 10.7 (though I have no idea how stable it is).

Answer (score 3):

I've started a new fork of `p4.el` at [`https://github.com/gareth-rees/p4.el`](https://github.com/gareth-rees/p4.el), and if you're a brave Emacs user who doesn't mind the occasional bug, you might want to give it a go. (Send me pull requests with your bug fixes!) I've been working on responsiveness in situations where the Perforce server might be intermittently available, such as when working over a mobile data connection. In particular, I've made the majority of user operations asynchronous, so that work is rarely blocked waiting for the Perforce server to respond.

I'm also adding support for new Perforce features like `p4 status` and `p4 annotate`, fixing bugs, and modernizing the code. [Here's a blog about what I've achieved so far.](http://garethrees.org/2013/05/01/p4.el/)

Comment: I am in, happy to see `cygwin` support :)

Comment: @MiserableVariable: I don't use Cygwin Perforce myself, so it could easily be broken (or I could have broken it). Bug reports and patches would be appreciated!

Comment: +1 thanks a bunch the old p4.el on sourceforge doesn't work with emacs-24 (it hangs when loading), yours seems to work fine so far!

Comment: Only got back to this question now - this sounds great Gareth, I'll certainly be checking this out.

Comment: Works nicely with Emacs 24.5.1